# Theorem 3.43 from baby Rudin

Tags: real-analysis

**Theorem.** Suppose

(a) $|c_1|\geqslant |c_2|\geqslant |c_3|\geqslant \dots;$

(b) $c_{2m-1}\geqslant 0, c_{2m}\leqslant 0,$

(c) $\lim c_n=0$

Then $\sum c_n$ converges.

Is it crucial that sequence $|c_n|$ is decreasing? What will happen if $|c_n|$ is increasing?

Comment: This is called Leibniz's rule. Is the series $1 - 2 + 3 - 4 + \cdots$ converging?

Comment: Not. I wrote my opinion about this below. You can check my post.

Comment: If $|c_n|$ is encreasing, then $c_n$ does not converge to $0$ as $n\to \infty$. Therefore, $\sum_{n=1}^k c_n$ does not converge to any real number as $k\to\infty$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it's Rudin, so my inclination is to say that there's not a single unnecessary punctuation mark in the book.

Here's what we'll do.  I remember like one divergent sequence ever, namely $\{ \frac{1}{n} \}$.  So let's try to build that.

I sort of want to let the odd factors just be that.  So let's take $c_{2n - 1} = \frac{1}{n} $, since they're supposed to be positive.  But that's not quite good enough, because I need to subtract something too.  So let's add a little something at the end and make it

$c_{2n -1} = \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{2n} $.

Now let's take $c_{2n} = -\frac{1}{2n}$, all of this for $n = 1, 2, \dots$.

Now the sequence $c_n \to 0$ and we have the alternating condition, but the sequence $\{|c_n|\}$ is not decreasing.

However, it's clear that $\sum c_n $ does not converge.

Comment: What is your example shows? Why this series does not converge?

Comment: Because the sum of the first 2n - 1 terms is just $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$, which diverges as $n \to \infty$

Comment: Thanks! Your example is great!